# C2783: Could not deduce template argument for a helper function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, binary-search-tree

I have a Node and BinaryTree class:

```
template<typename Elem>
struct Node {
    Elem Key;
    Node <Elem>* parent = nullptr;
    Node <Elem>* left = nullptr;
    Node <Elem>* right = nullptr;

    Node(Elem k);
};

template<typename Elem>
Node<Elem>::Node(Elem k):Key{k}{}

template<typename Elem>
class BinaryTree{
public:
    class iterator; //Node<Elem>*
    iterator root;
    void insert(Elem val);
    void remove(iterator& z);
};
```

With class iterator in BinaryTree implemented as:

```
template<typename Elem>
class BinaryTree<Elem>::iterator{
public:
    iterator();
    iterator(Node<Elem>* p);
    Node<Elem>* curr = nullptr;

    iterator& parent(); //set curr = curr->right
    iterator& left();
    iterator& right();

    void setparent(iterator& b);//sets this.curr->parent = b.curr->parent
    void setleft(iterator& b);
    void setright(iterator& b);

    iterator& Parent(); //Creates a new iterator that points to curr->parent and returns a reference to that
    iterator& Left();
    iterator& Right();

    Elem& operator *(); // returns curr->Key
    bool operator ==(iterator& b);
    bool operator !=(iterator& b);
    void operator =(iterator& b);

};
```

I made a minimum function to be used in the `BinaryTree<Elem>::remove(iterator& z)` function, implemented as:

```
template<typename Elem>
typename BinaryTree<Elem>::iterator & minimum(typename BinaryTree<Elem>::iterator & z) {
    while(z.Left().curr != nullptr) {
        z.left();
    }
    return z;
}
```

The remove function, when it calls `minimum()` with `z.Right()` as an argument, gives the error **C2783**, which states that:

**"BinaryTree::iterator &minimum(BinaryTree::iterator &)': could not deduce template argument for 'Elem'"**

The remove() function is implemented as:

```
template<typename Elem>
void BinaryTree<Elem>::remove(iterator& z) {
    if (z.Left().curr == nullptr) {
        transplant(*this, z, z.Right());//The z.Right() creates a new iterator on the heap, whose curr pointer points to z.curr->right
    }

    else if (z.Right().curr != nullptr) {
        transplant(*this, z, z.Left());
    }

    else {

        iterator y = minimum(z.Right()); //-> This gives the error C2783 and C2762 (no matching overloaded function found)
        if (y.Parent() != z) {
            transplant(*this, y, z.Right());
            y.curr->right = z.curr->right;
            y.Right().curr->parent = y.curr;
        }
        transplant(*this, z, y);
        y.curr->left = z.curr->left;
        y.curr->left->parent = y.curr;
    }
}
```

Comment: `iterator& Parent(); //Creates a new iterator that points to curr->parent and returns a reference to that` ... uhh, does this member function create the iterator as a local variable and return a reference to that local? Because using that reference would be undefined behavior (the local is destructed).

Comment: @cdhowie It creates a new iterator on the heap and returns a reference to it ```iterator* p = new iterator;```, then it sets the new iterator's curr to curr->parent ```p->curr = curr->parent;``` and returns the new iterator ```return *p;```

Comment: If the caller doesn't `delete` it though, then that's leaking. It would be better to return a non-reference (`typename BinaryTree<Elem>::iterator`). Otherwise the caller has to do something nasty like `iterator_type & i = z.Right(); /* use i */; delete &i;`. Remember that C++ is not garbage-collected; each `new` must have a matching `delete` -- and, ideally, you would not use them anyway, preferring smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` which will ensure deletion even if an exception is thrown. However, simple non-heap values should be preferred when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several contexts in which an argument to a template function is non-deduced.  The case where there is a template argument to the left of the `::` (scope resolution operator) is one such case.

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values ... do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead *use* the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified.
>
> 1. The *nested-name-specifier* (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator `::`) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id...

([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction))

So, in your example, everything to the left of the `::` operator in the function argument is in a non-deduced context:

```
template<typename Elem>
typename BinaryTree<Elem>::iterator & minimum(
    typename BinaryTree<Elem>::iterator & z
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
               non-deduced     deduced
)
```

Deduction fails simply because deduction is not attempted in this case.

Note that there is nothing to deduce on the right side.  However, there is in this example:

```
template <typename Elem>
void foo(std::vector<Elem> const &)
```

Deduction of `Elem` can be performed here because it does not appear to the left of the `::` operator.

The simplest workaround is simply to *not care* whether this is a `BinaryTree<Elem>::iterator` and just accept any type:

```
template <typename T>
T & minimum(T & z) { ... }
```